# Having the Client Communicate with a Process on the server

Tags: php, ratchet

I have an interactive cli program on the server ( a game ). I want to create a web app that communicates with this program. proc_open seems like it will do the trick but I have to close the process after processing each request.

This process output needs to be sent to the client and the client will respond with the appropriate input. Because it is a game this cycle can go on for a while.

My question is: How do I keep the process on the server running while waiting for client input.

I have done some research, and I was wondering if Ratchet IO (websockets) would be the best way to go?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a php tag, I am suggesting you to create a php script that can be run using a commandline which runs the ratchet wsserver.

I can give you an example written for laravel commandline:

```
class StartServer extends Command {

/**
 * The console command name.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $name = 'start:server';

/**
 * The console command description.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $description = 'Start WebSocket server';

/**
 * Create a new command instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
}

/**
 * Execute the console command.
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
public function fire()
{
    // This variable can be utilized before running the server
    $socket_server = new SocketServer();
    $server = IoServer::factory(new HttpServer(new WsServer($socket_server)), PORT);
    $server->run();
}
}
```

And your SocketServer Class would look something like this:

```
class SocketServer implements MessageComponentInterface
{
    public function __construct()
    {

    }

    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // New connection handle it, store it if necessary, make sure a session and connection is well mapped. Alternatively you can use Ratchet's SessionProvider
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        // Got message, do something with it
    }

    /**
     * @param \Ratchet\ConnectionInterface $conn
     */
    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        echo "Connection {$conn->resourceId} has disconnected\n";
    }

    /**
     * socket Error
     * @param \Ratchet\ConnectionInterface $conn
     * @param \Exception $e
     */
    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
        echo "An error has occurred: {$e->getMessage()}\n";
        $conn->close();
    }
}
```